# Can you make a WPBakery page builder VC_MAP dependency for an unchecked box?

Tags: visual-composer, wpbakery

I have a custom WPBakery page builder element that uses a checkbox and some text boxes for input. I would like to setup my vc_map dependancies so that when the box IS NOT checked the two text fields below it are show and when the checkbox IS checked they are hidden.

Everything I have seen online and in the docs seem to indicate a dependency with a check box can only show something when it is checked. Is it possible to reverse this behavior as I described above without a custom jQuery solution? ( that is what I am doing now, but want to avoid the extra JS )